# Asking questions about an internal or credential-requiring site

Tags: discussion, minimal-reproducible-example

I'm trying to scrape a site which is behind a credential login (there is no API for extracting the data) and [running into an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72422718/program-hangs-with-no-active-tasks). I've been unable to reproduce the issue on a public site.

I don't think it appropriate to include credentials to the site in a public forum. I also think it inadvisable to provide the precise CSS selectors I'm using while scraping -- information which could potentially be used by bad actors.

In short, I can't provide an MCVE.

How can I ask such questions on SO? Or are such questions off-topic for SO?

Comment: If you can't provide an MCVE the best we can do is guess. So all you get is 6 to 8 guesses.   Maybe you're better of with some rubber duck debugging first, try a chatroom to see if someone wants to act like one.

Comment: You should **never** post real credentials on the site. Some API keys are an exception, but if it's sensitive, don't post it. If it's a public API/website (both collectively referred to as API from here on out), they can get their own api keys or whatever. Otherwise, there is indeed a problem. If the problem is limited to that private API that no one else can access or get access to, then no, you shouldn't really post the question on SO, if you can't also include enough to reproduce or answer the question, depending on the exact problem

Comment: My point being, if the problem boils down to interaction between your code and a black box, private API that no one can in any way test against, no one will be able to help you either

Comment: In what way would your question be useful to other people in the future if you cannot provide any information about it?

Comment: You did not specify the difference between what you *expected* and what you see. Yes, you see messages about thread exits, but is there any behaviour that you do not expect otherwise? I am not a C# SME, but even a quickest of searches confirms those messages are nothing to worry about *by themselves*. This does not look like a question that needs access to the non-public resource to be debugged.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine It's not a private API, but a website behind credentials; but that's a distinction without difference. But I can't be certain the problem "boils down to an interaction with your code and a private API"; perhaps I'm using the specific technologies (`async`/`await`, `HttpClient`) incorrectly.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I would have expected the code to run all the asynchronous tasks to completion, and it doesn't. (Edited the question to reflect that.) There's nothing in the message itself that indicates a problem. But I think it significant that all the threads (presumably used by each async task) all exited together.

Comment: @VLAZ A valid answer from my perspective would be "This sounds like <x> or <y>. To rule out <x> try <x1>; to rule out <y> try <y1>." That would be useful for someone else who's trying something similar and comes across the same symptoms.

Comment: @ZevSpitz quoting my first comment, "API/website (both collectively referred to as API from here on out)" - api was a simplification because comment length limits are annoying. Since you're unable to reproduce it on a public site, it's likely that it boils down to that specific website. In either case, the point holds: if it can't be reproduced elsewhere, and remains specific to a black box no one can access or replicate locally, no one can help you

Comment: @OlegValter is correct; those aren't even errors. That's completely normal behavior. There is no problem there to even be solved.

Comment: @ZevSpitz that's already better, thanks. Now, it starts to look like you might be having an X/Y problem with this question. The message indicates that the thread exited normally, so you need to narrow down *when* it happens. After processing? After fetching? What about `if( retry == 10 )` rethrow? After HTML loading? Answering all those questions (use a debugger or sprinkle print statements - whatever) will help others understand what's happening. I am in serious doubt your question is in any way related to the structure of the resource.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't an exception swallowed in `Task.Run(async () => { }`? If it "hangs" where does it hang? In other words: When you break into the debugger at which statement is each thread? You do get passed `Task.WhenAll`, right?

Comment: @rene The debugger doesn't show me a specific statement, just a pane with some possible actions, like opening the Tasks view. The UI is responsive, so `Task.WhenAll` is successfully returning a `Task`, but I never see the debugger active statement past that line.

Comment: So if you add a Debug.Print after Task.WhenAll that will output a string? if yes, your code works, technically. As we lack the functional requirements what it is supposed to do we can't tell what is wrong.

Comment: @rene Adding `Debug.Print` after `Task.WhenAll` doesn't output a string.

Comment: Can you diagnose if you have ThreadPool starvation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vancem/diagnosing-net-core-threadpool-starvation-with-perfview-why-my-service-is-not-saturating-all-cores-or-seems-to-stall

Comment: @rene _Are you sure there isn't an exception swallowed_ I had set the HttpClient's Timeout to an hour. When I set it to something smaller, like 10 minutes, I get the following wrapped exception chain (outer to inner): TaskCanceledException -> TimeoutException -> TaskCanceledException -> IOException -> SocketException

Comment: @ZevSpitz well, that is something. So, the site you're crawling happily accepts all your connections but then takes its time to return a payload maybe because they notice you're scraping. How many connections do you have going at the same time? You're better of with failing early, backing off a bit and then retry and/or limit the maximum number of concurrent connections  with for example a semaphore: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL; DR;** First and foremost, Stack Overflow is a repository of Q&A intended to help *future* readers. If you can't reproduce the problem with a more generic example or share your actual working code, the question is much less likely to be found useful by others. Not to mention it may be impossible to help you without those details as further explained below. Lack of credential wouldn't invalidate an MCVE alone, but if one if required and you can't provide it, that may be grounds for closing the question.

---

To cover a few of your statements in more detail:

> I don't think it appropriate to include credentials to the site in a public forum

At the risk of sounding obvious, use fake secrets in sample code. An MCVE may require that the code be runnable by others, but it's understandable why a real credential wouldn't be provided. I have never seen a question closed for lack of MCVE when the asker hasn't provided a working secret, **because secrets should remain so**.

If you ever do accidentally share a secret:

1. Edit the actual secret out of your post (temporarily obfuscating it).
2. Flag the post for moderator intervention. Explain the situation with a custom mod flag and ask that they remove any post revisions with the secret in it.
3. Rotate the secret immediately.

You can also help with items 1 and 2 on others' posts if you have full edit privileges, but if not, you can still flag a moderator for assistance in removing the information.

> I also think it inadvisable to provide the precise CSS selectors I'm using while scraping

You can try to give less context in your question as to what you're scraping and why. However, sometimes you really *can't* share your code due to business policy, contractual obligations, or other reasons. In these cases, your question may be closed as off topic for lacking details if you can't share required information to answer your question.

**One tip I have here** (I've asked questions AD questions which could potentially expose authentication and authorization structure if not careful), is that often when internal data can't be exposed, you can still generalize the proprietary information with generic text, like `Property1`, `Property2`, `https://domain.tld`, etc. It's more work to do so, but as long as the data structure itself isn't considered proprietary you can almost always remove business information from your code samples so they both satisfy data sharing requirements by your employer and the requests for more information by this community.